# Turbolinks content reload load pages twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I am facing an issue in my site that there are multiple layouts, so when i move from one layout to another then I do

```
<meta name="turbolinks-visit-control" content="reload">
```

but issue is that i load my page twice or hit action twice

Comment: I do not understand the problem, about double rendering or incorrect rendering?

Answer (score 2):

This is the intended behaviour of the reload `turbolinks-visit-control`. When clicking a link, Turbolinks will request the page (hitting the action the first time). Then it will parse the response and notice the `turbolinks-visit-control` meta tag, and perform a full page reload (hitting the action the second time).

You should only need to use `turbolinks-visit-control` when you are sure you want a full page load.

Comment: Meanz there is no solution of it by which I can avoid it